# Infinite linear potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I am currently learning and solving Schrodinger's time independent equation for particles under various 1D-potentials.

Would it be possible to have a mix of a linear potential (of the form $U(x)=Fx$ for example) which is still infinite at every point (of the form $U(x)=\delta(x)$ for example)? The motivation would be that I want the particle to be moving in only one direction without being able to return in the other direction (as if it faces an infinite wall at every point).

I know the question is ill-formulated so please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: $\delta(x)$ is not infinite at every point, and it also doesn't as if you want that.

Comment: How is the potential linear and yet infinite at every point?

Comment: I think you're looking for a potential of the form $U(x)=Fx$ for $x>0$ and $U(x)=\infty$ for $x\leq 0$. I don't know how to solve it myself but this would correspond to a gravitational potential with a solid wall at $x=0$.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Airy functions are the solutions to such a potential well.